# How does the JavaScript-SVG Events correspondence work?

Tags: javascript, html, events, svg

Having worked with Inkscape for quite a while, now that I've started learning JavaScript, I was very keen to make interactive vector graphics. Nonetheless, I am having quite a difficult time understanding how certain aspects of different things work. Using this tutorial as a reference (http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/), I was wondering if someone might be able to aide me in my understanding by answering a few questions of mine regarding it:

1. It is my understanding that in the language of SVG, evt is just an alias for event, but what event exactly is it that it accepts as its argument? Is it running continuously and keeps accepting new arguments all the time, so that it accepts first a click, then a drag, then a release, then nothing, then nothing, then another click, drag, etc.?
2. Why is it that *onload="makeDraggable()"* is declared in `<svg ...>`, and why doesn't it work to have it declared in the individual `<path ...>`'s, nor to have it declared in `<body ...>`?
3. Why is it, that after the line

```
var transforms = selectedElement.transform.baseVal;
```

that when we change the values of *transforms*, the values of *selectedElement.transform.baseVal* changes too?

I hope my questions are not too fuzzy to be possible to answer them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `evt` in `makeDraggable` refers to the `onload` event, since the function is bound to the `onload` event by means of `onload="makeDraggable(evt)"`. In this case, the `evt` variable is simply used by JS to access the SVG object itself, by means of `evt.target`. The event target is the HTML element that has fired the onload event, which is in this case, the SVG element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In javascript, you can name the event property being passed into an event handler anything you want. `function startDrag(bob)` would work just as well. Every time one of your event handler functions is triggered, a *new* event object is created which is passed into the event handler function.
2. The makeDraggable function is creating the mouse event handlers on the whole svg file, but inside those event handler functions, they perform the drag on evt.target, which will be the element the mouse was over. Every time you click on something within the svg file, a new event object will be passed in that has an evt.target set to whatever your mouse was over.
3. baseVal is an object, and transforms is given a reference to the object, so any changes to transforms are the same as changes to baseVal. For more information, look up the difference between value and reference types in JavaScript.

Comment: Cheers mate! Very neat and comprehensive! Thanks! Especially for your answer to question no. 2. :)